# Heating 2 story bottom floor doesnt get warm

Tags: heating

I live in a 2 story house  when I run the heater it does not warm up the first floor,the heater is located on the second floor.

Comment: What sort of "heater?" A hot air furnace, especially if it shares ducts with air conditioning, probably needs to have dampers changed to drive hot air to the first floor in heating season, and cool air to the second floor in cooling season.

Comment: Has it always been this way or just recently? Are the registers on the first floor open?  Do you feel any warm air out of the first floor registers?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Heated air rises. Convection can only occur if the heat source is at the bottom. This applies equally to home heating or boiling water in a pan. As the lower area is heated it causes the air or water to become lighter, & therefore rise to the top. This forces the cooler, heavier air/water downwards towards the heat source, where again it is heated & the cycle of hot up/cold down continues.

Solution - move the heater to the lower floor.

Answer (score 1):

Not surprising, really, given that heated air rises. Any heat generated in the second storey will only rise even higher, and keep circulating, if there's enough of it for enough time, to keep that storey warm. It will not find its way down.

Of course, if there is a route from bottom to top, like a stairwell, this will happen much more effectively, and without that, it may not happen much at all.

By heating the lower storey, that will stay warm, and the heat (hot air) from it will rise to warm the storey above. Simple thermo-dynamics!